# Powershell: Re-order rows in file by date

Tags: sorting, powershell

I have an input file like this:
    Peter,Melbourne,30.5.1982
    Simon,Sydney,21.2.1990
    Tom,Adelaide,22.9.1980

What I'd like to do is re-order the content of the file by the date column and save it to a file.
Like:
    Tom,Adelaide,22.9.1980
    Peter,Melbourne,30.5.1982
    Simon,Sydney,21.2.1990

The whole thing should be done in Powershell..

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@vonPryz put a good answer, you can do it a bit shorter.

```
# Read input data
$c = Import-Csv -Header @("Name","City","Date") c:\temp\data.txt -Delimiter ","

# Get the good globalization info
$oz = new-object Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU")

#
$c | Sort-Object {[System.DateTime]::Parse($_.date, $oz)}

# Write output data
$d | Export-Csv c:\temp\datasSortedVyDate.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @vonPryz You can also have a look to `ParseExact` datetime static method.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Import-CSV` to read the data. Then convert each date to a DateTime object, so sorting will compare dates, not strings. Finally, sort the CSV data by Date column. Like so,

```
# Read input data
$c = Import-Csv -Header @("Name","City","Date") c:\temp\data.txt -Delimiter ","

# Print the data. This looks just like what we have read from the file
$c

Name  City      Date
Peter Melbourne 30.5.1982
Simon Sydney    21.2.1990
Tom   Adelaide  22.9.1980
```

Let's sort the data

```
$c | sort -Property Date
Name  City      Date
Simon Sydney    21.2.1990
Tom   Adelaide  22.9.1980
Peter Melbourne 30.5.1982
```

Huh? Sorting didn't work. This is as the Date column contains string values. In string sorting, the sort doesn't care about year part, as two first characters are enough to sort strings. This is common a caveat.

How to overcome this? One needs to convert the date into date objects that will sort nicely by comparing year and month parts too. First off, create a culture info that is used to tell if you are using mm-dd-yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, or some other format.

```
# Eh, mate, Melbourne is down under
$oz = new-object Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU")

# Loop through each row and convert the date member to date, using Aussie culture.
for($i=0;$i -ne $c.count; $i++) {
    $c[$i].Date = [Convert]::ToDateTime($c[$i].Date, $oz)
}

# Now the sort works as expected:
$c | sort -Property Date
Name  City      Date
Tom   Adelaide  22.9.1980 0:00:00
Peter Melbourne 30.5.1982 0:00:00
Simon Sydney    21.2.1990 0:00:00
```

Comment: +1 but using `Sort-Object` you can compute on what you sort, you can  also  use an hashing table for the -property parameter `sort-object -property @{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime - $_.CreationTime}; Ascending=$false}`

Comment: G'day mate, thanks for the solution, works a treat! :)
Good on ya!